# 504 Gateway Time-out nginx/1.14.0 (Ubuntu)

Tags: nginx

I'm getting 504 in my wordpress site recently. I have hosted my site in aws ec2 t2.micro instance.When i restart nginx the issue fixed.But after few hour the issue is back.Does the weight is big for t2.micro?Please help

Comment: Are you using NGINX for Wordpress instead of Apache, or are you using NGINX as a Front End Proxy?

Comment: Nano has 1GB RAM by the look of it. Is MySQL / MariaDB on the same instance? How much memory have you given it? I'd check `top` or similar on the running instance to make sure there is free memory.

Comment: I'm using nginx instead of apache @t2pe

Comment: Yes all in same instance.How much will cost me monthly for t2.large? @Rup

Comment: It might not be impossible to use a nano: there's a 256MB MySQL configuration included in the default install I think. But here's [the AWS EC2 pricing](https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/pricing/) - it'll depend on which region you're using and if you pre-pay with a reserved instance etc.

Comment: Do you have any idea why a line with a '0' displays on every page of my site.From the login page and every other pages in my site it displays. @Rup